# Get rectangle bounds for each letter in a image

Tags: java, algorithm, pseudocode

So I'm trying to fill an `ArrayList<Rectangle>` with the bounds of each letter of an image file.

For example, given this `.png` image:

[image]

I want to fill an `ArrayList<Rectangle>` with 14 `Rectangle`(one rectangle for each letter)

We can assume that the image will contain only 2 colors, one for the background and one for the letters, in this case, pixels will be either white or red.

At first, I thought I could search for white columns in between the letters, then if I found a completely white column I could get for example the width by getting the lowest red pixel value and the highest red pixel value and `width = maxX-minX` and so on:

```
x = minX;
y = minY;
w = maxX-minX;
h = maxY-minY;

letterBounds.add(new Rectangle(x,y,w,h));
```

The problem is that there's no space in between the letters, not even 1 pixel:

[image]

My next idea was for each red pixel I find, look for a neighbor that hasn't been seen yet, then if I can't find a neighbor I have all the pixels to get the bounds of that letter. But with this approach, I will get 2 rectangles for letters like "i" I could then write some algorithm to merge those rectangles but I don't know how that will turn out with other multi part letters, and before I try that I wanted to ask here for more ideas

So do you guys have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the OpenCV `cv2.findContours()` function. Instead of using the `cv2.drawcontours()` function for drawing the contours, which will highlight the outline of the letter, you could instead draw a rectangle on the image by using the `cv2.rectangle` and by extracting the coordinates from `cv2.findContours()` function.

Answer (score 1):

I think two step algorithm is enough to solve the problem if not using library like OpenCV.

1. histogram
2. seam calculation

## 1. histogram

```
C.....C..C...
.C.C.C...C...
. C.C....CCCC
1111111003111
```

- dot(`.`) means background color(white)
- `C` means any colors except background color(in your case, red)

accumulating the number of vertical pixels with non-background color generates histogram.

```
        *
        *
******..****
0123456789AB
```

It is clear the boundary exists at 6 and 7

## 2. seam calculation

Some cases like `We`, cannot be solved by histogram because there is no empty vertical lines at all.

**Seam Carving algorithm** gives us some hints

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seam_carving

More detail implementation is found at

- [princeton.edu - seamCarving.html](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall13/cos226/assignments/seamCarving.html)

#### Energy calcuation for a pixel

[image]

The red numbers are not color values for pixels, but energy values calculated from adjacent pixels.

The vertical pathes with minimal energy give us the boundary of each characters.
[image]

## 3. On more...

Statistical data is required to determine whether to apply the seam carving or not.

- Max and min width of characters

Even if histogram give us vertical boundaries, it is not clear there are two or more characters in a group.